# Executing docker login in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am relatively new to docker and have a docker-compose file where I want to access a private repository.

Since the docker-compose file will also run on other computers, I would like to integrate the `docker login` command into the docker-compose file.
So that `docker-compose up` is executed and then as with `docker login` the user data must be entered.

Is this possible at all?

Unfortunately in my search so far I have not found a way to integrate the command.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; there's no way to specify repository credentials in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  (And you definitely would not want to commit them to source control or distribute them in a plain-text file even if it were possible.)  You need to manually run `docker login` on each system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the stupid question, but is there a specific reason for this?
The login data would still have to be entered by the user. The only difference is that the user would have to execute one command instead of two.

Comment: If there's no way to put credentials in the file that lists what images to run, then there's no way to accidentally leak those credentials in to source control.  It's also usually the case that everyone who will run the file will have their own set of credentials, or else you're using some sort of automation tool that can run the `docker login` step on its own.

Comment: David Maze IMHO that is not docker-compose job. Yml files are full of MySQL passwords and so on so there’s no point. They should at least be able to read a .credentials file or something.